# How to use regularexpression for this example?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write regular expression for this line:

`-  5.0   -  4.0   -  3.0  ... +  12.0`

That It could group floats with sign in a single group (-5.0,-4.0...)

I have tried:

`\s*([+](?:\s)*\d*[.])`

But apparently It does not ignore non-capture group inside capture group.
Any suggestion how this could be solved?

Comment: There maybe a better way if you provide more details about the problem. Is the input data a string? where are you getting the input from. If you can format it differently earlier it could be easier to deal with the data. Also if you want a really easy way to just test a bunch of lines of data you should give this site a try. http://pythex.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your capture group has the following elements:

- `[+]` matches a literal `+`
- `(?:\s)*` matches any number of whitespace characters
- `\d*` matches any number of digits
- `[.]` matches a literal `.`

So right now, that matches a plus sign followed by space followed by digits followed by a decimal point. But it sounds like you want to match *several* sign-space-digits-decimalpoint-digits sequences in a row, as long as they have the same sign. I'd do that like this:

1. Start with the expression to match a single such sequence:

   ```
   [+-]\s*\d+[.]\d+
   ```

   This matches plus or minus, then space, then digits, decimal point, digits.
2. You'll want to save the sign to make sure that the rest of the pattern only matches sequences with the same sign. So make a capturing group.

   ```
   ([+-])\s*\d+[.]\d+
   ```
3. Now let's repeat the pattern (with some intervening space) to match another group, except that we want to make sure the sign is the same so we use a backreference.

   ```
   ([+-])\s*\d+[.]\d+\s*\1\s*\d+[.]\d+
   ```

   The `\1` matches whatever was matched by capturing group number 1. In this case, that's the sign, `+` or `-`. This pattern will match two consecutive sequences that have the same sign.
4. Now change the second part of the pattern to match zero or more additional sequences.

   ```
   ([+-])\s*\d+[.]\d+(?:\s*\1\s*\d+[.]\d+)*
   ```
5. Finally, you can allow for spaces before and after the match. This can be solved with judicious use of the [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.search) function, or [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.findall), rather than [`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.match). You can then use [`match_object.group()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) with no arguments to get the sequence that was matched, which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

According to your requirement:

> That It could group floats with sign in a single group (-5.0,-4.0...)

The solution using `re.findall()` function:

```
s = '-  5.0   -  4.0   -  3.0  ... +  12.0'
signed_floats = [re.sub(r'\s+', r'', f) for f in re.findall(r'-\s*\d+\.\d+\b', s)]

print(signed_floats)
```

The output:

```
['-5.0', '-4.0', '-3.0']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you can try:

```
(\+|-)\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*
```

Although, you will always have a trailing comma, so you'd have to remove it.

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sv0qjx/2)